# Finding files in Buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have saved several daily files in various buckets. The file name has a fixed format but the bucket does not.
The file name is company_raw_date.tgz like...

```
company_raw_2010-12-03.tgz
company_raw_2010-12-04.tgz
company_raw_2010-12-05.tgz
company_raw_2010-12-06.tgz
```

But the bucket can be s3://sales/december or s3://archive/company
The same name can be found in several buckets and the data may or may not be the same.

My question is how do I search across all buckets for a given date and download all files found along with their bucket names.

Comment: Please give some light on technology/platform you are using for this ?

Comment: s3cmd is the package that is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it from a webapplication that you want to download the s3 files. If so, AWS java SDK is there to meet your requirements.

I did  the same for my java struts2 webapplication.

Answer (score 0):

AWS's all SDKs have support for getting the list of buckets configured as a part of your account. If you want an easier way follow the REST call as follows:

```
   GET / HTTP/1.1
   Host: s3.amazonaws.com
   Date: date
   Authorization: signatureValue
```

See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/RESTServiceGET.html for more information.